# Accounting Program Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apps, oracleapplications, oracle-application-server

I have Oracle Application R12 running on 11g.

The error occurs in **Accounting Program** when we are running **Create Accounting** session in **Payable Module**.
When we click on Diagnostics it gives this message :

> This request finished with an error and produced the following
>   completion message: An internal error occurred.  Please inform your
>   system administrator or support representative that:
>
> An internal error has occurred in the program
>   xla_ap_acct_hooks_pkg.main.  Technical problem : Error encountered in
>   product API for extrac
>
> The processing began on 24-MAR-2015 09:11:13
>   and ended on 24-MAR-2015 09:12:16. You may find more information on
>   the cause of the error in the request log or the concurrent manager
>   log.

and if we click on View log it gives this :

> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+ Subledger Accounting: Version : 12.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1979, 1999, Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> XLAACCUP module: Accounting Program
>   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> Current system time is 25-MAR-2015 11:09:05
>
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> **Starts**25-MAR-2015 11:09:06
>   **Ends**25-MAR-2015 11:10:43 An internal error occurred.  Please inform your system administrator or support representative that:
>
> An internal error has occurred in the program
>   xla_ap_acct_hooks_pkg.main.  Technical problem : Error encountered in
>   product API for extract An internal error occurred.  Please inform
>   your system administrator or support representative that:
>
> An internal error has occurred in the program
>   xla_ap_acct_hooks_pkg.main.  Technical problem : Error encountered in
>   product API for extract
>   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+ Start of log messages from FND_FILE
>   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 25-MAR-2015 11:25:17 - Executing Unit Processor ... 25-MAR-2015
>   11:25:17 - Initializing variables 25-MAR-2015 11:25:17 - Security
>   Context Set  25-MAR-2015 11:25:17 - Ready to cache the Application and
>   Ledger Level Sources ... 25-MAR-2015 11:25:21 - Cached the Application
>   and Ledger Level Sources 25-MAR-2015 11:25:22 - Entering the loop to
>   read document units from the queue ... 25-MAR-2015 11:25:22 - Checking
>   status of the parent Accounting Program 25-MAR-2015 11:25:22 -
>   Dequeuing the unit from the queue 25-MAR-2015 11:25:22 - Fetching
>   event information for the documents in the unit 25-MAR-2015 11:26:00 -
>   executing extract hook event key =
>   527717-11312076-1219A353A3BA70B9E05400144F2BF644 25-MAR-2015 11:26:03
>   - extract hook executed successfully
>   *************************************************************************************************** The following REVERSAL events could not be processed. The
>   event/process status is U/U:  Note: this warning may be ignored for
>   any events whose ledger is a cash-basis ledger
>   -------NO SUCH EVENTS-----------
>   *************************************************************************************************** 25-MAR-2015 11:26:40 - executing postprocessing hook event key =
>   527717-11312076-1219A353A3BA70B9E05400144F2BF644 25-MAR-2015 11:26:40
>   - postprocessing hook executed successfully 25-MAR-2015 11:26:40 - Completing Journal Entries 25-MAR-2015 11:26:41 - Checking status of
>   the parent Accounting Program 25-MAR-2015 11:26:41 - Dequeuing the
>   unit from the queue 25-MAR-2015 11:26:41 - Fetching event information
>   for the documents in the unit 25-MAR-2015 11:26:43 - executing extract
>   hook event key = 527717-11312076-1219A353A3BB70B9E05400144F2BF644
>   25-MAR-2015 11:26:47 - extract hook executed successfully
>   *************************************************************************************************** The following REVERSAL events could not be processed. The
>   event/process status is U/U:  Note: this warning may be ignored for
>   any events whose ledger is a cash-basis ledger
>   -------NO SUCH EVENTS-----------
>   *************************************************************************************************** 25-MAR-2015 11:26:51 - executing postprocessing hook event key =
>   527717-11312076-1219A353A3BB70B9E05400144F2BF644 25-MAR-2015 11:26:51
>   - postprocessing hook executed successfully 25-MAR-2015 11:26:51 - Completing Journal Entries 25-MAR-2015 11:26:51 - Checking status of
>   the parent Accounting Program 25-MAR-2015 11:26:51 - Dequeuing the
>   unit from the queue 25-MAR-2015 11:26:51 - Fetching event information
>   for the documents in the unit 25-MAR-2015 11:26:52 - executing extract
>   hook Technical problem : Error encountered in product API for extract
>   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+ End of log messages from FND_FILE
>   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+ Executing request completion options...
>
> Finished executing request completion options.
>
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+ Concurrent request completed Current system time is 25-MAR-2015
>   11:10:43
>
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Screenshots are in the attachment to get better idea !!

Thanks in advance !!

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [MOS Doc ID 1964046.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1964046.1) it appears as though you will need a patch.

**Note:** While it is typically SO best practice to include quotes from whatever source you are linking it is actually violating the ToS with Oracle to quote their MOS documentation. I like my support contract, TYVM.

Also there could be an issue with this, please reference [MOS Doc ID 1582378.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1582378.1) :

> *************************************************************************************************** The following REVERSAL events could not be processed. The
>   event/process status is U/U: Note: this warning may be ignored for any
>   events whose ledger is a cash-basis ledger -------NO SUCH
>   EVENTS-----------
>
> ---

If this is a production environment I highly recommend opening an SR to confirm that this is the only issue you are seeing.

Comment: What would you suggest for a clone environment ??

Comment: For a non prod environment?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the following reason.

There is some orphan record exists in xla_transaction_entities table. Delete those lines from the table. It will be Ok. To identify the record, you can use the below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM xla.xla_transaction_entities xla_tran_ent
WHERE 1 = 1
AND application_id = 200
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM xla_ae_headers xla_header
WHERE 1 = 1
AND xla_header.application_id = xla_tran_ent.application_id
AND xla_header.entity_id = xla_tran_ent.entity_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ap_invoices_all ap_inv
WHERE xla_tran_ent.source_id_int_1 = ap_inv.invoice_id
AND xla_tran_ent.entity_code = 'AP_INVOICES')
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ap_checks_all ap_inv
WHERE xla_tran_ent.source_id_int_1 = ap_inv.check_id
AND xla_tran_ent.entity_code = 'AP_PAYMENTS')
```